# Optimised code (like did in ruby) for swapping digits at odd places for 2 numbers in C#

Tags: c#, ruby

I am ruby developer and for certain case I need to swap digits at odd places  in 2 numbers in `C#`.

I have coded in ruby in basic way like below,

```
a = 35321
b = 123456
a1, b1 = a.to_s.chars, b.to_s.chars # ['3', '5', '3'. '2', '1'], ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'] 

n = [a1.length, b1.length].min - 1 # => 4
```

swapped in below manner,

```
n.times do |i|
  if i.odd?
    temp = a1[i]
    a1[i] = b1[i]
    b1[i] = a1[i]
  end
end
```

Or optimised code is below using `step` method in ruby,

```
1.step(n,2) { |i| a1[i], b1[i] = b1[i], a1[i] }
```

And at the end I get numbers as per expectation as,

```
> a = a1.join.to_i
# => 32341 
> b = b1.join.to_i
# => 153256
```

My problem is I could not figure out how can I do same in `C#` Appreciated if anyone provide either suggestion.

Comment: The problem is you have written your ruby code, but haven't explained your problem sufficiently in natural language. what does it do, what are the input parameters, what do you mean by odd numbers, do you mean odd as in the 0 based index?

Comment: Calling code that converts number to string "optimized" is somewhat strange. Is your requirement "code must be a single statement"? (check if what you are trying to do fits [codegolf.se] better)

Comment: @MichaelRandall I tried best to clear idea, not odd numbers, it says odd places (odd power index could sound btter I guess). Input is clearly just 2 numbers.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I found difficult to swap odd places digits for two numbers without converting them in string array. It is little optimised, I do not clain best solution, I am just interested in C# proficient code. Still improvement in above ruby code to do same will be appreciated, as it will give me better approach.

Comment: Just use a for loop and a char arrays; use modulo and do some arrhythmic. If you want it one line, then make it a method. Which part are you having trouble with

Comment: @MichaelRandall I think I should post my C# code first even if it is not perfect and then check for better solution from others, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways in `c#` to get your desired output but I give you a solution that you can understand easily,

First of all we declare your integer array in `c#` like

```
int input1 = 35321;
int input2 = 123456;

int[] a = input1.ToString().Select(t => int.Parse(t.ToString())).ToArray();
int[] b = input2.ToString().Select(t => int.Parse(t.ToString())).ToArray();
```

Then we use traditional for loop to swap number between two array with odd index

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)    //<= Loop through on first array
{
     if (i % 2 != 0)                  //<= Check for odd index
     {
          int q = a[i];               //<= Take element from first array with current index
          a[i] = b[i];                //<= Swap element from second array to first array on current index
          b[i] = q;                   //<= Swap element from first array to second array on current index
     }
}
```

Then we simply print your desired output by,

```
int number1 = Convert.ToInt32(string.Join("", a));
int number2 = Convert.ToInt32(string.Join("", b));

Console.WriteLine("Output for first array: \t" + number1);
Console.WriteLine("Output for second array: \t" + number2);
```

**Output:**

[image]

## Demo

Comment: I appreciate for your response and going with explanation but what I have is two numbers in input, not an array. And output is also 2 numbers after operation performed.

Comment: You missed that inputs are also numbers

Comment: Why do you need 2 loops here because swapping must be placed for numbers on same index. Also you do not need two local variables `q` & `w` to hold values, 1 was enough.

Comment: I did little same already till now. +1 for time and right answer

Comment: glad to hear, :)

Answer (score 1):

Considering  the inputs a and b will be strings.
The below code should get you the desired result.

`var result = string.Join("", b.ToString().Select((x, i) => (i % 2) == 0 || a.ToString().Length <= i ? x.ToString() : a.ToString().Substring(i, 1)));`

this code will take into consideration the difference in length.

**Edit**:You can also implement using LINQ avoiding loops and considering a and b as numbers as shown below.

```
int[] ai = a.ToString().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();
int[] bi = b.ToString().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();

var number1 = string.Join("", bi.Select((x, i) => (i % 2) == 0 || ai.Count() <= i ? x.ToString() : ai[i].ToString()));
var number2 = string.Join("", ai.Select((x, i) => (i % 2) == 0 || bi.Count() <= i ? x.ToString() : bi[i].ToString()));

Console.WriteLine("Array 1:" + Convert.ToInt32(number1));
Console.WriteLine("Array 2:" + Convert.ToInt32(number2));
```

Comment: @ray Mark as the answer if this is what you were looking for :)

Comment: a and b are numbers and not arrays so `Select` will not work on number. Please update answer properly.

Comment: Consider a and b are numbers and proceed!